# phpMyAdmin - Error : The mbstring extension is missing

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm getting this phpMyAdmin error:

> ****The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.****

I've searched for this solution many times and implemented step by step but still getting the same error.A couple of days back, it was running fine and now don't know what happened.Please help!

Here are my **php.ini** settings:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir="C:\php\ext"


extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
```

Comment: You have to restart your http server after changing the php configuration of you are using php as a module inside the http server. Afterwards check if the extension could be loaded by using the `phpinfo()` function. If that is not possible, then you certainly get an entry naming the reason in your http servers error log file. What does it say in there?

Comment: I've restarted my HTTP but still it's giving me error @arkascha

Comment: And what did you find in the error log file? (Assuming you did not just ignore what I wrote...)

Comment: sorry don't know how to do this.I'm a newbie in PHP @arkascha

Comment: OK, no problem, we all started. But you should not simply ignore things you do not understand at first glance. The `phpinfo()` function is documented (like all of phps functions), the documentation includes a simple example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php The "error log file" is one of the log files your http server writes. It contains all issues that arise while your http server is restarted for example. So in it you can probably read why the extension fails to load. Check your configuration to locate that file, you will need that for programming anyway, no way around that.

Comment: Thanks! but can you explain that in simple words? like what should I do with this function? I run this function and gives me all the info about system and etc. so now? @arkascha

Comment: You should check in there if the extension is loaded in there or not. Most likely the answer is "no". By that you know more exactly where to look: if it is _not_ loaded, then something fails during the startup of the http server (when the loading is done). You have to find out _why_ loading that extension fails. And that is easiest, as said above, if you look into the error log file.

Comment: I upvoted your question so that you have more than the minimum required 20 reputation points here to use the `chat` feature: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105478/phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing

Comment: My php.ini file path (C:\xampp\php\php.ini) is written there, right next to "Loaded Configuration File" . @arkascha

Comment: Sure, and there also should follow a list of all loaded extensions and their configuration...

Comment: yes exactly! Then? @arkascha

Comment: Please see two comments above: I created a chat room for us. That should make communication easier.

Comment: see the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035220/opensuse-phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing/44944076#44944076

Answer (score 3):

Please try to put the complete path for the extension directory and it works.

```
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Or

[Check This Post](http://www.dailytechnoblog.com/how-to-resolve-phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I had that problem, the solution is easy, only follow this.

1. Stop the server and then install this php version.

   $ service apache2 stop

   $ sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-common
2. You must install this package for Laravel and the composer.

   $ sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl php7.1-xml php7.1-zip php7.1-gd php7.1-mysql php7.1-mbstring
3. view the new version.

   $ php -v

   you can see that.

> PHP 7.2.4–1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Apr 5 2018
>   08:53:57) ( NTS )

1. now, you need remove php 7.0

   $ sudo apt-get purge php7.0 php7.0-common
2. Now restart your server

   $ sudo shutdown -r now
3. Now your server use PHP 7.2 and you can solution mbstring error.

   $ sudo a2enmod php7.2

   $ service apache2 restart