# openSUSE phpmyadmin Error: The mbstring extension is missing

Tags: phpmyadmin, opensuse, mbstring

> phpMyAdmin - Error
>
> The mbstring extension is missing. Please check
>   your PHP configuration.

I hava installed php-mbstring and php-gettext, my php version is php7.
And I installed php and phpmyadmin through zypper.

Comment: What does the output of `phpinfo()` say about mbstring functionality?

Answer (score 0):

1. install mbstring and restart your apache:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
   sudo service apache restart
   ```

then remove ; from your php.ini file:

```
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

If it still doesn't work..remove your php setup, without removing the databases from your phpmyadmin. Reinstall it.

NB: * if you want to remove all, all mention the one you need to.

```
sudo apt-get remove php*
```

Then install the php and modules of the php version that you need. here, php 7.1:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-fpm php7.1-curl php7.1-gd php7.1-bz2 php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-json php7.1-tidy php7.1-mbstring php-redis php-memcached
```

restart your apache and check the php version.

```
sudo service apache restart
php -v
```

when all this is done, execute the following command to enable mbstring forcefully and restart your apache.

```
sudo phpenmod mbstring
sudo service apache restart
```

following the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php) for php upgrade:

Hope it helps.
It did to me :)

Comment: Just a note: OpenSUSE doesn't use `apt-get` but `zypper`.